# nodemailer falling on server but works well locally

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

Sending mail via nodemailer using a google account working perfectly while running locally, but fails on server.

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "Gmail", 
    auth: {
        user: "my email ",
        pass: "my pass"
    }
});
```

Comment: try by using `nodemailer-smtp-transport` module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652481/node-mailer-errorunsupported-configuration-downgrade-nodemailer-to-v0-7-1-to