# unable to email in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemail npm package.

I configured the options like this:

```
function feedback(req, res, next){
    console.log('feed back given....', req.body);
    smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        ignoreTLS: false,
        tls: { rejectUnauthorized: true },
        debug: false,
        auth: {
            user: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
            pass: "xxxxxx" 
        }
    });

    //Mail options
    mailOpts = {
        from: from: req.body.email,
        to: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
        subject: 'EMAIL FROM Rsc-student: ' + req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.message
    };

    smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
      //Email not sent
      if (error) {
          res.send(error);
          console.log('error sending mail');
      }
      else {
          res.send(response);
          console.log('success sending mail');
      }
    });
}
```

If I am not wrong, I configured correctly but still unable to send mail. Its printing the error case

Comment: can u share `error`?

Comment: ```from: from: req.body.email,``` make sure this line is correct!

Comment: from: from: req.body.email, change this line to-  from:  req.body.email

Comment: @user29 its just printing the console in if condition

Comment: Do it `console.log("The error is :", error);`

Comment: Print error message using `console.log(error);`

Comment: log error console.log(error) instead of your custom error message           console.log('error sending mail');

Comment: my bad i didn't print error properly. Now its printing `error sending mail:  [Error: Unsupported configuration, downgrade Nodemailer to
v0.7.1 to use it]`

Comment: take look at this link https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#use-the-default-smtp-transport to create transport

Comment: You can refer this link [Node Mailer Error:“Unsupported configuration, downgrade Nodemailer to v0.7.1 to use it” in localhost][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652481/node-mailer-errorunsupported-configuration-downgrade-nodemailer-to-v0-7-1-to

Comment: I downgraded to 7.1 and now its printing `error sending mail:  { [Error: 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_S
ERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
] stage: 'init' }`

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra `from:` from `mailOpts`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this 3 steps:

1. Login to your Gmail account.
2. Follow this link [allow gmail to send mail over less secure app](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).
3. Select **on** option.

It works for me. I hope it will help you.

Comment: its just printing the console in if condition